# What went into the process of Luke Skywalker getting a new hand?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, luke-skywalker

Luke's hand is cut off, and a robot is later shown attaching/tweaking his new robotic hand.

Is it known how much time and effort went into getting Luke a new hand? Was it a quick process (maybe a day or two) to attach it?

And once he had his hand, how long did it take him to get usability back? Was this also a quick process?

Comment: How long did it take? 11 Parsecs

Comment: I'm strongly recommending that this be split up into smaller more precise questions

Comment: I felt like these were too closely related to split up since one leads directly to the other.

Comment: Oh, it was a nightmare. They ordered it from Geonosis -  the first one was sent to Tatooine and, when it finally arrived, it only had three fingers. The second came direct but was a lefty and the middle finger didn't bend...that had to go back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the script [here (Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back)](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html) there is no evidence of any long periods of time between his hand being chopped off and a new one being attached.

> EXT. SPACE
>
> The Falcon soars into infinity and away from the huge Star Destroyer 
>   which seems, by contrast, to stand still.

This is just after picking up Luke, then a few lines down they dock on a huge Rebel Cruiser.

> EXT. SPACE - REBEL CRUISER
>
> The Millennium Falcon is attached to a huge Rebel cruiser by a docking 
>   tube.

Then the next we hear from Luke (a few more lines) he is being worked on by a medical droid.

> INT. STAR CRUISER - MEDICAL CENTER
>
> Luke speaking into the comlink **as a medical droid works on his hand**.
>   Leia stands near him while Threepio and Artoo look out the window.

Now as for the *functionality* of the hand I think this is also evidenced in the script after it is repaired he seems to be able to use it fully. (Of course it may take a bit of lightsaber training for full previous prowess)

> Luke looks down at his hand.  A metalized type of bandage has been 
>   wrapped around his wrist.  The **medical droid makes some adjustments in 
>   a tiny electronic unit**, then pricks each one of Luke's fingers.
>
> LUKE: 
>   Ow!
>
> Luke wriggles his fingers, makes a fist, and relaxes it.  His hand is 
>   **completely functional**.

There's not much more to say, It seems to say that it was completely functional after it had been integrated with him. This seemed to happen in minutes to hours instead of days.

At the start of the next movie the script describes Luke as having returned to Tatooine without any previous mention of his name in the script it is safe to presume that he did not do any intermittent training of his hand.

> Luke Skywalker has returned to his home planet of Tatooine in an 
>   attempt to rescue his friend Han Solo
>
> [Star Wars: Return of the Jedi](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html)

Comment: I don't see how anything from these script quotes provides any information one way or the other.

Comment: @Buzz the script quotes are used as an aid to show how little time needed to pass.